# Using Entity Framework Code First in production best practices

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm starting to writing big ASP.NET MVC application and i planning to use EF code first approach for database interaction, but what i'm supposed to do when some part of application will be ready and i face problem with changing database structure slightly?

EF Code-First need to create database everytime when model changes or it fails with "Model compatibility cannot be checked because..." exception, i know that the only way to avoid this is exclude metadata check from conventions, but i belive that this is not good option.

So is there any robust solutions?

Comment: This is a good candidate for integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

You can also avoid the exception calling `Database.SetInitializer<YOUR_DBCONTEXT>(null);`

The "oficial" way to do this is called "Code First Migrations", the ADO.NET team recently released the first beta: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-with-magic-walkthrough-automatic-migrations.aspx